# Update several objects in transaction maner in mongo(morphia)

Tags: mongodb, transactions, morphia

I have two entites

```
@Entity
public class Place  {

    private int rating;

    public void addRating(int rating) {
        rating+=rating;
        datastore.save(this);
    }
}

@Entity
public class User {

    private int rating;

    public void addRating(int rating) {
        rating+=rating;
        datastore.save(this);
    }
}
```

I need to update two objects in atomic maner. I'm afraid, that mongo has no transaction support. Is there a best way to do this in safe maner?

```
 user.addRating(3);
 place.addRating(3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do it in an atomic fashion, change your data structure. Everything you would have inside a transaction needs to go into a single document. There's no other way to simulate transactions.

If this is absolutely not possible with your data, MongoDB is the wrong tool for the job.

PS: Having the datastore inside the entity is an "interesting" approach IMHO.